# How can I force the path to be scaled to fit in the svg tag?

Tags: svg, path

I have an svg tag which contains a rect and a path, the width and height of all of them is fixed to 100%. The problem is that the path is exceeding the bounds of the svg and so the path is clipped. 
How can I scale the path to be automatically fitted in the svg bounds ?

Comment: use a viewBox rather than percentage units

Comment: Thanks but how to determine the parameter of the viewBox automatically ? I mean I don't already know where to put it using other units. What I want is simply to fit the path in its container. I think there should be a way to do this, but I don't know it.

Comment: call getBBox() on the path. Set the viewBox accordingly.

Comment: Thanks ! It works :)